# checking if GPS Alert is present or not

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, uialertview

I want to check if an alert is already present on my window or not. The alert is that of GPS (sumthing like "your app" will like to use your current location with Don't Allow and Allow buttons). I want to set some flag if this alert is present on screen. If anyone knows it, then please help me in getting this solved.

Comment: you get this alert only once when your app tries to use location manager for the very first time may be you can do your things just after starting location manger

Comment: ya, I have thought of using a flag and resetting it for the very first time. But I want to detect if the alert is present or not.

Comment: that alert is  system generated may be try to listen to some notification which gets published when that alert appears

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
  NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
  if ([subviews count] > 0)
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
      return YES;
}
return NO;
```

this will help...

Comment: I have tried this, but I think this method is useful when you are presenting the alert using [alsertView show];. Its not working in case of iPhone alerts (like that of location services)

Comment: Can i ask,for what purpose do you want to check this alert is present or not.? So that we can give you  better suggestion according to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for **ios4.2 or later** than you can `authorizationStatus` of `CLLocationManager` class.

For this you will need to check `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` variable if its value is `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` then it the alert will be shown.

In **iOS 5** or later  their is one option through which use can reset the location warning in that case also the status will be `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. So if your application is running and user switches to setting to reset that property than you will need to implmenet the following delegate method of `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            //If this is the case than alert will be shown
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:

            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:

            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Thanks,